# How to embed only particular division of my GWT application to another web application?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, embed

I have an existing GWT Application with an HTML page containing some `<div>` tags:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="employeetracker/employeetracker.nocache.js"></script>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV ID = "I1" />
    <DIV ID = "I2" />
    <DIV ID = "I3" />
<BODY>
</HTML>
```

As we know GWT converts everything to javascripts and stores that in "employeetracker.nocache.js". Now I want only `<div id="I2"` of this application to use in one of my another web application. In the other web application I tried to create another HTML page with only division `<div id="I2"` and tried to import the javascript created by my GWT project to it.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<ABS-Path>/employeetracker.nocache.js"></script>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV ID = "I2" />
<BODY>
</HTML>
```

But that doesn't seems to be working. Can anyone suggest a better approach to do this?

Comment: Did you try including the other `HTML` page under the `welcome-file-list` in your `web.xml`?

Comment: Fixed formatting, removed superfluous tag